# Javacript / Jest . Is there a way to add `.toMatchSnapshot` for each `it` test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

Is there a way to add `.toMatchSnapshot` for each `it` test?
If I have a lot of tests like that

```
describe('components/Footer.tsx', () => {
  it('renders a Footer', () => {
    const { asFragment } = render(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Footer />
      </MemoryRouter>,
    )
    expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
  it('renders a Component2', () => {
   
  })
  it('renders a Component3', () => {
   
  })
  ...
  it('renders a ComponentX', () => {
   
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an utility function for that.

```js
const testComponentRenders = (name, component) => {
  it(`renders ${name}`, () => {
    const { asFragment } = render(component);
    expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
}


describe('components/Footer.tsx', () => {

  ;[
    { 
      name: 'footer', 
      component: (
        <MemoryRouter>
          <Footer />
        </MemoryRouter>
      )
    },
    {
      name: 'component1',
      component: <component1 />
    },
    ...
  ].forEach(testCase => testComponentRenders(testCase.name, testCase.component));

});
```

Comment: I thought about something like 
`afterEach(() => { callSnapshotTest() })`

Comment: AFAIK something like that is not possible. You could store the result of `asFragment()` inside a global variable with access it in the `afterEach()`, but please don't do that, that will lead to horrible side effects and does not solve your problem of repeating the same statement over and over.

Comment: what side effects it could cause? Because I wanted to like that before I've read your message 
`let component: DocumentFragment;`
`afterEach(() => {  expect(component).toMatchSnapshot())   }) `
`component = asFragment()`

Comment: As long as you are running your tests in band (one after each other) this _should_ be fine, but when you run them in parallel  things get messed up + debugging failing tests gets very hard too.

Comment: So what is the best practice you think for that case?

Comment: When you are just rendering plain components that don't need any additional setup logic I would recommend using an array of components an an utility function executing the test (like the example I showed).